# powershell remoting to exchange: Set-CASMailbox does not have property ActiveSyncBlockedDeviceIDs

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server, powershell-remoting

I am trying to set up a service that disables a user's exchange access by remote powershell to the exchange server and executing like so:

```
    Set-CASMailbox -Identity usern -OwaEnabled $False
    Set-CASMailbox -Identity usern -EwsEnabled $False
    Set-CASMailbox -Identity usern -EcpEnabled $False
    Set-CASMailbox -Identity usern -MapiEnabled $False
    Set-CASMailbox -Identity usern -MapiBlockOutlookRpcHttp $True
    Set-CASMailbox -Identity usern -EwsAllowMacOutlook $False
    Set-CASMailbox -Identity usern -EwsAllowOutlook $False
//THIS ONE FAILS:
    Set-CASMailbox -Identity usern -ActiveSyncBlockedDeviceIDs "USERSDEVICEID"
```

ERROR: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ActiveSyncBlockedDeviceIDs'.

when I do a Get-Command, from the exchange server itself, it *does* show ActiveSyncBlockedDeviceIDs in the list of parameters that Set-CASMailbox accepts, however when i do a Get-Command from my c# code on the remote server, it DOES NOT show ActiveSyncBlockedDeviceIDs in the list of parameters!!!  am I missing something?  is the Set-CASMailbox commandlet different between the one that runs on the server and the one that is exposed remotely?  or is this field not supported?  (or any other tree I should bark up to get this to happen via a wcf service that is not executing on the exchange server?)

my C# code to execute this from the remote server is like so:  (try... blocks,etc removed)

```
  WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(
    new Uri("http://" + server + "/Powershell/Microsoft.Exchange"),
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange",
    credential);

      Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);

      PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
      ps.Runspace = runspace;

      //none of these seem to make any difference if i add them or not.
      //ps.Commands.AddScript(@"Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'");
      //ps.Commands.AddScript(@"Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010");
      ps.Commands.AddScript(@"Get-Command");

      runspace.Open();
      var psResult = ps.Invoke();

      //iterate through and find parameters for Set-CASMailbox
      foreach (var res in psResult) {
        if (res.Members["Name"].Value.ToString()=="Set-CASMailbox") {
           foreach (var mem in res.Members) {
            if (mem.Name == "ParameterSets") {
              Console.WriteLine(mem.Value);
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Outputs list or parameters:

(ActiveSyncBlockedDeviceIDs is not there, nor is ActiveSyncEnabledDeviceIDs for that matter)

```
[-Identity] <MailboxIdParameter> 
[-ActiveSyncDebugLogging <Nullable`1>] 
[-ActiveSyncEnabled] 
[-ActiveSyncMailboxPolicy <MailboxPolicyIdParameter>] 
[-DisplayName <String>] 
[-DomainController <Fqdn>] 
[-ECPEnabled] 
[-EmailAddresses <ProxyAddressCollection>] 
[-EwsAllowEntourage <Nullable`1>] 
[-EwsAllowList <MultiValuedProperty`1>] 
[-EwsAllowMacOutlook <Nullable`1>] 
[-EwsAllowOutlook <Nullable`1>] 
[-EwsApplicationAccessPolicy <Nullable`1>] 
[-EwsBlockList <MultiValuedProperty`1>] 
[-EwsEnabled <Nullable`1>] 
[-HasActiveSyncDevicePartnership] 
[-IgnoreDefaultScope] 
[-ImapEnabled] 
[-ImapEnableExactRFC822Size] 
[-ImapMessagesRetrievalMimeFormat <MimeTextFormat>] 
[-ImapSuppressReadReceipt] 
[-ImapUseProtocolDefaults] 
[-MAPIBlockOutlookNonCachedMode] 
[-MAPIBlockOutlookRpcHttp] 
[-MAPIBlockOutlookVersions <String>] 
[-MAPIEnabled] 
[-Name <String>] 
[-OWAEnabled] 
[-OwaMailboxPolicy <MailboxPolicyIdParameter>] 
[-PopEnabled] 
[-PopEnableExactRFC822Size] 
[-PopMessagesRetrievalMimeFormat <MimeTextFormat>] 
[-PopSuppressReadReceipt] 
[-PopUseProtocolDefaults] 
[-PrimarySmtpAddress <SmtpAddress>] 
[-SamAccountName <String>] 
[-ShowGalAsDefaultView] 
[-Verbose] 
[-Debug] 
[-ErrorAction <ActionPreference>] 
[-WarningAction <ActionPreference>] 
[-ErrorVariable <String>] 
[-WarningVariable <String>] 
[-OutVariable <String>] 
[-OutBuffer <Int32>] 
[-WhatIf] 
[-Confirm]
```

Comment: Are you using the same account on both the local and remote sessions when you do the get-command?

Comment: i believe so.  I tried passing null, my account, and the service account we intend to use for the PSCredential, all with the same results.

Comment: The cmdlets you get in those remoting sessions are customized according to the RBAC roles the connecting account belongs to. You many not get all the cmdlets, or you may get some cmdlets but be missing some parameters of those cmdlets if you don't belong to the appropriate RBAC roles to perform those functions.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds promising. I'll look into that on Monday...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got back to this problem.  mjolinor's suggestion helped me.  Needed to add the service account to the appropriate RBAC role. (Exchange Managers I think).  After that, ActiveSyncBlockedDeviceIDs and ActiveSyncEnabledDeviceIDs showed up in the list of available parameters for the Set-CASMailbox command.  Interesting to note that those were the only 2 missing, and the only 2 that showed up after adding to the role.